# Prove that $f$ must be constant

Tags: complex-analysis

Hi I was working on the following problem:

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded region. Suppose that $f$ is continuous in $\overline{\Omega}$ and holomorphic in $\Omega$, $f$ is zero-free in $\overline{\Omega}$ and $|f|$=constant on $\partial\Omega$.

(a) Prove that $f$ must be constant.

(b) Is the boundedness condition imposed on $\Omega$ essential?

My reasoning is so far the following:

(a) Since $|f|$=constant (say $c$) on the boundary $\partial\Omega$, then by the maximum modulus principle, $|f|\le c$ on the region $\Omega$ and $f$ is constant if the equality holds at any point. If $c=0$ this shows that $f\equiv 0$ which is a contradiction of the fact that $f$ is zero-free. Therefore $c$ must be positive. Now since $f$ is zero free $\frac{1}{f}$ is analytic continuous on the closure and of constant modulus $\frac{1}{c}$ on the boundary. Then $|\frac{1}{f}|\le|\frac{1}{c}|\Rightarrow |f|\ge c$ and so $f$ is constant.

(b) Yes it is essential. Let's consider $f(z)=e^z$ on the right half plane.

Is my reasoning right? Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems fine to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes your reasoning is correct.  Notice that you also have the "minimum principle" which is proved in the way that you point out.  A holomorphic function is allowed a minimum inside a domain if and only if that minimum is zero.

A fun thing to think about on your part b:  Notice that the right half plane is biholomorphic to the unit disc (by a linear fractional mapping no less).  The point at infinity will be mapped to a point on the boundary of the disc.  So you get a bounded domain and a function for which $|f|=c$ on the boundary (at all but one point, where you could "define it" to equal say $c$).  What goes wrong?  The function $f$ is not continuous near that one point of the boundary of the disc that corresponds to the point at infinity on the right half plane.  Meaning that you also have an example of why continuity is needed, if $f$ is not continuous on the entire closure of omega, then it could be that $|f|=c$ on the boundary and $f$ not constant.